# How can I show the items in the given code in a beamer presentation in order after each other by clicking?

Tags: beamer, presentations, animations, slideshow

I am a beginner in beamer. How can I show the items in the beamer in order by clicking after each other?

More precisely, in the given code and picture, I want that first, the items in the red path appear; then by clicking, the items in the blue path (while the latter is still visible); and finally by clicking, the items in the green path (while the two latter are still visible).

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

    \smallskip
    \textbf{\textcolor{black}    {\fontsize{ 11}{ 11 }  \selectfont  Three flowers:}}
    \medskip
    \begin{columns}

        \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
            \fontsize{ 7 }{ 7 } \selectfont{ 1.Blue}.
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{fig11}
            \end{center}
        \end{column}

        \begin{column}{0.32\textwidth}
            \fontsize{ 7 }{ 7 } \selectfont{ 2. Yellow.}
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{fig22}
            \end{center}
        \end{column}

        \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
            \fontsize{ 7 }{ 7 } \selectfont{3. Violet}.
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{fig33}
            \end{center}
        \end{column}

    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beamer columns are overlay-aware, this means you can specify with e.g. `\begin{column}<2->` on which overlays a column should be visible. In the code below, I'm using the shortcut  `<+->` which means that a new overlay should be created and the column should be displayed from this new overlay onward until the end of the frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    
    \smallskip
    \textbf{\textcolor{black}   {\fontsize{ 11}{ 11 }  \selectfont  Three flowers:}}
    \medskip
    \begin{columns}
        
        \begin{column}<+->{0.3\textwidth} 
            \fontsize{ 7 }{ 7 } \selectfont{ 1.Blue}.
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}
            \end{center}
        \end{column}
        
        \begin{column}<+->{0.32\textwidth} 
            \fontsize{ 7 }{ 7 } \selectfont{ 2. Yellow.}
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}
            \end{center}
        \end{column}
        
        \begin{column}<+->{0.4\textwidth} 
            \fontsize{ 7 }{ 7 } \selectfont{3. Violet}.
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}
            \end{center}
        \end{column}
        
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(for more information on overlays, see the beamer user guide, section "3.10 Using Overlay Specifications")

Comment: I have another question: does this shortcut work if I want that figs 2 and 3 appear at the same time (by one click)?

Comment: @charmin Sure, use `\begin{column}<.->{0.4\textwidth} ` for your 3rd column